# How to make JS file apply to content brought in through AJAX jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I asked a question about this code earlier, but now I have another.

I followed an AJAX tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwngGtboldU ) to learn how to prevent certain sections of a website from loading. You can see at 17:50 he clicks the links and, rather than the entire page loading, only a certain section loads in.

This is all working great for me. However, I have an init.js file that I'd like to apply to content/cats.php. Even though init.js is included in header.php, it isn't applying to content/cats.php when it's pulled in. How might this be fixed?

I've tried putting

```
 <script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

at the beginning of cats.php and at the beginning of content/cats.php , but this doesn't work.

I'm using XAMPP.

My code:

style.css

```
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}

ul#nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

ul#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#PureTestDiv {
    background-color:red;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
}

#PureTestDiv2 {
    background-color:blue;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    display:none;
}
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>History API</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>  
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>


<body>

    <nav id="main">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="cats.php">Cats</a></li>
            <li><a href="dogs.php">Dogs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

footer.php

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var nav, content, fetchAndInsert;

                nav = $('nav#main');
                content = $('section#content');


                //Fetches and inserts content into the container
                fetchAndInsert = function(href) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost/WebsiteFolder/content/' + href.split('/').pop(),
                        method: 'GET',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            content.html(data);
                        }                    
                    });
                } 


                //User goes back/forward 
                $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                    fetchAndInsert(location.pathname);
                });


                nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');

                    //Manipulate history
                    history.pushState(null, null, href);

                    //Fetch and insert content
                    fetchAndInsert(href);


                    e.preventDefault();            
                });

            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

cats.php

```
<?php
require 'views/header.php';
?>

<section id="content">
    <?php require 'content/cats.php'; ?>
</section>

<?php
require 'views/footer.php';
?>
```

content/cats.php

```
Cats say meow
<div id="PureTestDiv">PureTestDiv 1</div>
<br>
<div id="PureTestDiv2">PureTestDiv 2</div>
```

dogs.php

```
<?php
require 'views/header.php';
?>

<section id="content">
    <?php require 'content/dogs.php'; ?>
</section>

<?php
require 'views/footer.php';
?>
```

content/dogs.php

```
Dogs say woof
```

init.js

```
$(function () {

    $('#PureTestDiv').click(function () {  
        $('#PureTestDiv2').fadeIn();
    });


});
```

This fiddle shows that the code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/mgswrv55/

Comment: What is in the init.js file?

Comment: Sorry, please check the updated version of my post. I've edited content/cats.php , style.css , and I've included init.js . I've also included a jsfiddle of what should be happening. But instead cats.php is nonresponsive when loaded in through AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple solution, the js file **does** get loaded and the jQuery selector applies to all the elements to all the elements that existed at the time the js file was run, which does not include the AJAX loaded content.

If an element doesn't exist when .on() is called, the event will not bind to it.

If you wish to add event handlers to dynamically loaded content you should use the following:

```
$(parentElement).on("click", selector, function(event) { 
    //your code
});
```

In your specific case the following code should funtion:

```
$(document).on("click", '#PureTestDiv', function(event) { 
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: I marked as solved because I feel like this should be the correct answer. However, it's still not working on my side, no idea why. I feel like I'm definitely closer with your help, though.

Comment: Only additional gotcha is to ensure the parent element exists when the first on() is called. Wrap the js in js.init in a document on load and ensure the parent element exists and you should be fine. Otherwise I'm afraid I don't have enough info to help

Comment: Thank you. Got it working now! Your solution was, indeed, the key. Just had a silly error that was still backing things up which I now fixed. Thanks again.